# linq Command not getting the answer for DB

Tags: linq

i have a table(UserQuestions) in my DB(WebSiteUsers) which contains QuestionID field as a Primary key and QuestionContext field which holds the Questions that are asked as its value. 
Now i want to have a textBox that show me the QuestionContext Value by getting QuestionID. 
I used these linq commands and none of them bring me the correct answer :

```
string Questioncontext = new WebSiteUsersEntities().UserQuestions.Where(p => p.QuestiuonID.ToString() == QuestionID).Select(p => new { p.QuestionContext}).ToString();
    string Questionx = (from q in new WebSiteUsersEntities().UserQuestions where q.QuestiuonID.ToString() == QuestionID select q.QuestionContext).ToString(); 

    QuestionCntxt.Text = Questionx;
```

the outcome is like this :

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[QuestionContext] AS [QuestionContext]
    FROM [dbo].[UserQuestion] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  CAST( [Extent1].[QuestiuonID] AS nvarchar(max)) = @p__linq__0

Comment: Posting the `UserQuestion` class would help. Also the correct tag (EF, which version etc.)

Comment: UserQuestion is a table in my data base this is the table :                   create table UserQuestion
(QuestiuonID int Primary Key identity,
UserID uniqueIdentifier foreign key references aspnet_Users(UserId),
QuestionTitle Nvarchar(max),
QuestionContext nvarchar(max),
DateAsked datetime 
)

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `QuestionID` variable is of type `string`, while the database column is of type `int`.

So rather than using

`q.QuestiuonID.ToString() == QuestionID`

criteria inside the query, convert the variable to `int` and use that as criteria.

Also `ToString` just gives you the SQL query text, not the result. Use `ToList` if you expect more than one result or `FirstOrDefault` if you expect zero or one results:

```
var questionID = int.Parse(QuestionID);
string Questioncontext = new WebSiteUsersEntities().UserQuestions
    .Where(p => p.QuestiuonID == questionID)
    .Select(p => p.QuestionContext)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that I also changed the `select` to return directly `QuestionContext` string rather than anonymous object having `QuestionContext` property.

Comment: thats it. FirstOrDefault  solve the problem. thatk you